# Validating form from ajax call with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a farm that loads when an option is seleceted with ajax call, however i want to validate my form, immediately when i submit, it and there is error upon validation, the ajax called form dissapears.

This is my ajax

```
        <script>
function salesType(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","showsalestype.php?&q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        e.preventDefault();
    }


}
</script>
```

my php

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
if($q == 'POS'){ ?>
  <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">POS Referece No <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                  <input id="atmref" name="atmref" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  type="text" value=" ">
                                                </div>
                                                <p><font size="2" color="#ff0000"> <?php echo $form->error("atmref"); ?> </font></p>
                                            </div>
<?php  }  ?>
```

How do i prevent the ajax call to remain upon validation error

Comment: do you meen `if (str == "")` with 'validation'? Where do you call the `function salesType(str)`?

Comment: The form on php above is called when an option appeared, and i want to validate with php in such that if the called form is not filled after submission, it shld echo error and retain the form , instead of dissapear